# Find occurrence of column (string) in other column SQL

Tags: sql, string, search, text, sas

I try to find the occurrences of a string in another column.

If the string occurs more than once (in a joined column), then I want to remove it.

Extract of my data (issue) see photo below.

This is the SQL that I started.

```
SELECT 
    t1.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NAME, 
    t1.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME, 
    t1.BIRTH_NAME as BIRTH_NAME, 
    compress(t1.FIRST_NAME) || compress(t1.LAST_NAME) || compress(t1.BIRTH_NAME) as full_name_no_space
FROM 
    atable t1
```

Column 4 "full_name_no_space" joins "first_name", "last_name" and "birth_name".

The data is inconsistent meaning "first_name" can contain the first & family name of a person etc. Thus there are duplicate entries in the joined column "full_name_no_space" which I try to remove.

[image]

Comment: Concatenating null-columns may result in null. Also, "compress" may not do what you think it does. Check the documentation for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, does this work?

```
(case when compress(t1.first_name) like '%' || compress(t2.last_name) || '%' and
           t1.first_name <> t2.last_name
      then ''
      when compress(t1.first_name) like '%' || compress(t2.birth_name) || '%' and
           t1.first_name <> t2.birth_name
      then ''
      else compress(t1.first_name) 
 end) ||
 (case when compress(t1.last_name) like '%' || compress(t2.birth_name) || '%' and
           t1.first_name <> t2.birth_name
      then ''
      when compress(t1.last_name) like '%' || compress(t2.first_name) || '%' 
      then ''
      else compress(t1.last_name) 
 end) ||
(case when compress(t1.birth_name) like '%' || compress(t2.first_name) || '%' 
      then ''
      when compress(t1.birth_name) like '%' || compress(t2.last_name) || '%' 
      then ''
      else compress(t1.birth_name) 
 end)
```

This basically goes through the comparisons to see if something already matches -- and if not, then to include it in the result.

Comment: Some of the names where missing through this statement but it helped me anyway to process and think about a solution. What finally worked for me is the following function: TRANWRD(TRANWRD(compress(t1.FIRST_NAME_TXT), compress(t1.LAST_NAME_TXT), "") ||  compress(t1.LAST_NAME_TXT), (t1.BIRTH_NAME_TXT), TRANWRD(compress(t1.FIRST_NAME_TXT), compress(t1.LAST_NAME_TXT), "") || compress(t1.LAST_NAME_TXT)) as FULL_NAME_NO_DUPL. If the new field already exisits in the joined field then don`t add.